# Galera mysql check for HAProxy

Tags: mysql, database, haproxy, galera, isalive

I am using `Galera` cluster with 3 nodes. I am using `HAProxy` as a load-balancer. I currently using a `mysql` check script that is written for `Percona` cluster and after some deadlock problems I suspect that the script may be the issue. I've modified the script to work with `Galera` cluster but it is not good enough.

I am looking for a `mysql` check script that is dedicated to `Galera`.

Comment: "Check"?  Check the time of day?  Check the CPU usage?  Check the FK constraints?  Check what??

Comment: I mean health-check that can tell HAProxy if it should or should not send queries to a specific node, like `option mysql-check` of HAProxy, which is not satisfying because it does not check the cluster status. I don't want to specify what metrics I want to check, cause I don't know what is the best practice health-check and metrics for galera cluster nodes.

Comment: I know this is bit late so you might have solved it, but it won't be your check script which is the problem if it is deadlocks. The issue will be write queries to multiple nodes at the same time. Sometimes you can change the queries, but sometimes your app has to just deal with the deadlock and retry the code which is an issue.